# Sort by the association with populate

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have Articles and Comments linked by a one-to-many association (an Article can have many Comments).

I would like to obtain the most commented articles so I proceed like that :

```
function mostCommentedArticles () {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  Article.find().populate('comments').sort('comments ASC').exec(deferred.makeNodeResolver());
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

BUT, I don't obtain the expected result : it doesn't sort at all (by Comments or anything else)

Is there an other way to proceed or is it an issue?

Thanks,

Pierre

Answer (score 11):

You pass it in the second parameter of `.populate()` like this:

```
.populate('foo', { sort: 'comments ASC' }).exec(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither waterline (0.10.22) or sailsjs (v0.11) currently support this.
You would need to process your return variable to reorder the data.

There is a ticket for this at https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/334

There is a difference between

```
 function mostCommentedArticles () {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  Article.find().populate('comments').sort('comments.comment_date ASC').exec(deferred.makeNodeResolver());
  return deferred.promise;
 }
```

and

```
function mostCommentedArticles () {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  Article.find().populate('comments', {sort: 'comment_date ASC'}).exec(deferred.makeNodeResolver());
  return deferred.promise;
 }
```

The first one should return all the articles and comments with everything sorted by the comment_date.
The second one should return all your articles with the attached comments where the comments are sorted by date.

The second one should work using mongodb.

Comment: does waterline supports the first one ?

Comment: No, I don't believe at the time that it did (as per the link). I have the 2 pieces of code to highlight the differences between the sorting.
Apologies if this made it confusing.
I haven't looked into it for a while so I'm unsure what the current status is

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/334) might point you in the right direction:

```
.populate('foo', { where: [ '1' ]);
```

You can find more on the where operator [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md)

But be aware that you for now won't be able to easily filter by both a model's *native* fields, and of populated fields - [issue on hithub](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/281).