# Dynamic Sorting according to populated value?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

There is a table named house which has many-to-many association with location table. Have to sort the list by the value of the location.street. Is there a way to sort the result of the query according to the value of the populated field?
I tried:

`House.populateAll().sort("location.street ASC").exec(console.log);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort by the association with populate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996210/sort-by-the-association-with-populate)

Answer (score 0):

Neither waterline (0.10.22) or sailsjs (v0.11) currently support this.
You would need to process your return variable to reorder the data.

There is a ticket for this at https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/334