# SailsJS Perform sorting on populate data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Here is my current **event model**:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        client: {
            model: 'client',
            required: true
        },
        location: {
            model: 'location',
            required: true
        }
    }
};
```

**The client Model:**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        address: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        clientContact: {
            model: 'user',
            required: true
        }
    }
};
```

So how do I implement sorting based on the *`client name`* and also have the *`skip`* and *`limit`* property(for pagination) to work along with it.

I tried using the following query:

```
Event.find({ id: ['583eb530902db3d926345215', '583eb6dd91b972ee26dd97b1'] },
           { select: ['name', 'client'] })
           .populate('client', { sort: 'name DESC' })
           .exec((err, resp) => resp.map(r => console.log(r.name, r.client)));
```

But this does not seem to do it.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996210/sort-by-the-association-with-populate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waterline doesn't support sorting a result by child records like this.  If `client` was a *collection* of child records attached to an event, then your code would sort each of the returned `Event` record's populated `client` array by name, but I'm assuming in this case `client` is a singular association (i.e. `model: 'client'`).

If what you want is an array of `Event` records sorted by the name of their client, you can do it relatively easily using Lodash after you retrieve the records:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

Event.find(queryCriteria).populate('client').exec((err, resp) => {
  if (err) { /* handle error */ }
  var sortedRecords = _.sortBy(eventRecords, (record) => { return record.client.name; });
});
```

Comment: But Lodash wont let me paginate the data. Thanks anyway.